# How do I add a globally available MetaMethod on Object in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

(this is a generalized example)

I'd like to create a utility method that can be called on any object, it'll have a signature like:

```
class StringMetaData {
    Object value
    String meta
}

Object.metaClass.withStringMetaData = { meta ->
   new StringMetaData(delegate, meta)
}
```

With the idea that then anywhere in my program I could do something like:

```
def foo = 1.withStringMetaData("bar")
```

And now I can grab `foo.value` for the value or `foo.meta` for the attached String.

Within a local context, I'm able to define this meta method on Object, but I'd like to make it available globally within my application, what's the right way to make this metamethod available everywhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps a groovy extension module could help you. I never tried it myself, but the documentation states, that you can add custom methods to JDK classes.

Comment: +1 The documentation [is over here](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Creating+an+extension+module)

Comment: Might want to note that this feature only works on Groovy 2.0 or newer.